# HTML email formatting bugs in Outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, formatting

I have been working on an html email. It has generally worked in tests but gets mangled in Outlook. I have seen the questions on here and have been reading a decent amount on it, but after trying a variety of fixes nothing's worked. I am a total novice using dreamweaver, so I know the code might be horrendous:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<!-- utf-8 works for most cases -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<!-- Forcing initial-scale shouldn't be necessary -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<!-- Use the latest (edge) version of IE rendering engine -->
<title>EmailTemplate-Hybrid</title>
</head>
<body width="100%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="margin: 0;" yahoo="yahoo">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%" bgcolor="#e0e0e0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr>
    <td><center style="width: 100%;">

        <!-- Visually Hidden Preheader Text : BEGIN -->
      <div style="display:none;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;mso-hide:all;font-family: sans-serif;"> Historic Renovation. </div>
        <!-- Visually Hidden Preheader Text : END -->

        <div style="max-width: 100%;"> 
          <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width"100%" align="center">
            <tr>
            <td>
            <![endif]--> 

          <!-- Email Header : BEGIN -->
   <table width="60%" height="auto" align="right">
            </table></div></center></td><td style="font-size: 2.75vw;"><a style="color: black" href="http://www.ernstbrothers.com/gallery/residential/">GALLERY </a></td>
            <td style="font-size: 2.75vw;"><a style="color: black" href="http://www.ernstbrothers.com/services/">SERVICES</a></td>
        </tr></table>
     <table class="container " width="100%">
      <td>

        <img style="display: block" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/79b319fc2b7f0621f7b66caec/images/b9d5dc85-0cfc-470f-a3e6-7abaffb8849d.jpg" width="100%">
        </td>
          </table>
                    <!-- Email Header : END --> 

                <!-- Email Body : BEGIN -->      
            <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="background: #FFFFFF; font-size: 4vw; font-family: serif; text-align: right " width="100%" height="125px"><blockquote>
                  <p><a style="color: black" href="http://ernstbrothers.com/blog/solebury-guest-house-part-18th-century-bones/">HISTORIC RENOVATION</a> </p>
                </blockquote>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- 1 Column Text : BEGIN -->
            <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td>
     <img style="display: block" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/79b319fc2b7f0621f7b66caec/images/b1bd7d4c-a5f9-4081-a543-b94b4cf6d9d2.jpg" width="100%">
                </td>
              </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
     <a href="http://www.ernstbrothers.com/blog/solebury-guest-house-part-18th-century-bones/"><img style="display: block" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/79b319fc2b7f0621f7b66caec/images/328fa1bb-1858-4f8c-9c89-2002fd132365.jpg" alt="" width="100%"></a>
                </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
     <table>
     <tr>
     <td>
      <h1 style="font-family: sans-serif; text-align: left; font-size: 4vw; line-height: auto; padding-top: 20px; padding-left: 20px; color: #000000;"> Another Project in <span style="color: #4CA7A0"><a style="color: teal" href="http://ernstbrothers.com/blog/solebury-guest-house-part-18th-century-bones/">Bucks County!</a></span></h1>
         </td>
        </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                     <p style="text-align: center; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 3vw; line-height: auto; color: #000000"> Ernst Brothers is fulfilling the new owners vision for this property in Solebury, creating a serene guest house from the bones of this 18th-century farmhouse.</p>
                      </td>
         </tr>
          </table>
                      <!-- Button : Begin -->

                      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="right" style="margin: auto;">
                        <tr>
                          <td style="border-radius: 3px; background: #222222; text-align: center;" class="button-td"><a href="http://ernstbrothers.com/blog/solebury-guest-house-part-18th-century-bones/" style="background: #222222; border: 15px solid #222222; padding: 0 10px; color: #ffffff; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 2.75vw; line-height: 1.1; text-decoration: none; display: block; border-radius: 3px; font-weight: bold;" class="button-a"> 
                            <!--[if mso]>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]-->Read <span style="text-align: left"></span>More
                            <!--[if mso]>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]--> 
                            </a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
          </table>
                         <!-- Button : END -->

                     <!-- Visit US : BEGIN --> 


  <!-- Two Even Columns : END --> 

          <!-- Email Body : END --> 

          <!-- Email Footer : BEGIN -->
          <table width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="http://www.ernstbrothers.com/contact-us/"><img style="padding-top: 40px; display: block" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/79b319fc2b7f0621f7b66caec/images/374d5aa5-5dd8-4a96-89e2-2a392f6092c3.jpg" alt="" width="100%">
            </a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="http://www.ernstbrothers.com/contact-us/"><img style="display: block" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/79b319fc2b7f0621f7b66caec/images/4441e9d8-1138-44e9-95ee-cd59c1019d9d.jpg" width="100%"></a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
<table width="100%" height="200px" style="background: #FEFDFD">
            <td style="text-align: center; font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', 'Myriad Pro', 'DejaVu Sans Condensed', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 4vw; line-height: auto;"><a style="color: black" href="http://maps.apple.com/?q=Ernst+Brothers&amp;sll=40.186293,-75.227316&amp;z=10&amp;t=s"> 1104 North Bethlehem Pike <br>
Spring House, PA 19477</a></td>
          </table>
<table width="100%" height="147" border="1" align="center" style="background-color: darkgrey">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="15%" align="center"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/ernstbrothers/"><img style="display: block" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/79b319fc2b7f0621f7b66caec/images/391b81fc-92ee-4072-b859-dc538485f046.png" alt="" width="80%"></a></td>
      <td width="15%" align="center"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/ErnstBrothers/"><img style="display: block" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/79b319fc2b7f0621f7b66caec/images/e5447cda-cd97-45b1-9411-6703b985f3b2.png" alt="" width="80%"></a></td>
      <td width="15%" align="center"><a href="https://twitter.com/ErnstBrothers"><img style="display: block" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/79b319fc2b7f0621f7b66caec/images/b88e145d-feda-4b66-86fe-6aea5083e760.png" alt="" width="80%"></a></td>
      <td width="15%" align="center"><a href="https://www.houzz.com/pro/ernstbrothers/ernst-brothers"><img style="display: block" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/79b319fc2b7f0621f7b66caec/images/ba8cce9e-385a-4827-964d-fa608ffce6b2.png" alt="" width="80%"></a></td>
      <td width"40%" style="font-size: 3vw; font-family: sans-serif; text-align: center"><a style="color: white" href="tel:+2154535124">215-453-5124</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
          <!-- Email Footer : END -->
                    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]-->   





            <center>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="canspamBarWrapper" style="background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top:1px solid #E5E5E5;">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px;">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="canspamBar">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" valign="top" style="color:#606060; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:11px; line-height:150%; padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left:20px; text-align:center;">
                                        This email was sent to <a href="mailto:*|EMAIL|*" target="_blank" style="color:#404040 !important;">*|EMAIL|*</a>
                                        <br>
                                        <a href="*|ABOUT_LIST|*" target="_blank" style="color:#404040 !important;"><em>why did I get this?</em></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="*|UNSUB|*" style="color:#404040 !important;">unsubscribe from this list</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="*|UPDATE_PROFILE|*" style="color:#404040 !important;">update subscription preferences</a>
                                        <br>
                                        *|LIST:ADDRESSLINE|*
                                        <br>
                                        <br>
                                        *|REWARDS|*
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <style type="text/css">
                    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
                        table#canspamBar td{font-size:14px !important;}
                        table#canspamBar td a{display:block !important; margin-top:10px !important;}
                    }
                </style>
            </center></body>
</html>
```

Here is how it's intended to look, opened in chrome from the .html on my desktop. [IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hNZ3.jpg)

Here is what it looks like in Outlook. [IMG2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtRJm.jpg)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: But... what is the problem? You speak of general formatting only.

Comment: Anyway here a guide tu css in email: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/selectors/child/

Answer (score 0):

Email is NOT front-end Web development. I used to use Dreamweaver for email development but had to abandon it since it would not let me use a mix of html 5 and older versions. That's the problem, email programs support a limited version of CSS3 and some don't support it at all.

Outlook is notorious because it doesn't follow a standard HTML rendering engine like Webkit. It's based on Microsoft Word.

**Widths**

Outlook doesn't really support a width wider than 800px. Gmail is similar. So `width=100%` will give you inconsistent results.

**Fonts**

Outlook straight up doesn't understand something like `style="font-size: 2.75vw;"` Try something like `style="font-size: 18px;"`

**Images**

For images, Outlook will respect a something like `<img width="580">` but may not respond to `<img width="100%">`. I find it ignores widths in the inline style, but other programs use them very well.

Try something like this:

```
<img src=""http://www.gwally.com/news/photos/catintinfoilhat.jpg" 
alt="A boy and his cat" width="580" align="center" style="max-width: 100%; width: 580px;"/>
```

I'm having issues getting my testing accounts to work, so I can't give as much help as you need. I think if you address these issues, it will take you further down the path to a consistent email.

For further information, this is a great resource on what works in email:

- http://campaignmonitor.com/css/